# Сортировка данных в laravel

Tags: laravel

Мне нужно получить последнии 10 записей в виде 1-2-3-4-5

Как я сортирую:

```
            $message['mess'] = Chat::where([
                ['owner', '=', $owner],
                ['to', '=', $to],
            ])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(10)->get();
```

В итоге я получаю вид 5-4-3-2-1. Если поменять `desc` на `asc` получаем нужны порядок, но при этом он достает первые 10 записей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте отсортировать уже полученную коллекцию:

```
$message['mess'] = Chat::where([
  ['owner', '=', $owner],
  ['to', '=', $to],
])->latest()->limit(10)->get()->sortBy('created_at');
```

P.S. *latest()* заменяет конструкцию *orderBy('created_at', 'desc')*